# What is the purpose of the nottracked="false" attribute in an HTML anchor?

Tags: html, html-email

I recently came across this attribute while inspecting the HTML source of a recent email I received. It appears to be an attribute used within an `<a>` element. Astoundingly, a Google search turned up nothing specific related to this attribute.

A simple usage example for this attribute appears as follows:

```
<a href="some url" nottracked="false" style="some css, etc."><img src="some image URL" style="some image css, etc."></a>
```

Does anyone know what this anchor attribute does and/or why it is used? Where on the web is this documented?

Comment: that doesn't seem to be a default HTML attribute.

Comment: It's not a default attribute. I wonder if it's something that is added by an email-client for internal purposes, but I have no idea if that's the case or not. There is very little information about this attribute, but it seems what little there is all stems from email-code, and is an `<a>`-tag attribute. It's NOT official, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nottracked` attribute is used by Infusionsoft's email marketing software to opt links in HTML email messages out of Infusionsoft's link tracker. It is non-standard. Elements with `nottracked="false"` or missing a `nottracked` attribute altogether typically contain an Infusionsoft tracking URL and have a class name starting with `inf-track-` followed by a numeric ID.

According to [Infusionsoft's help center](http://help.infusionsoft.com/userguides/campaigns-and-broadcasts/email-templates-and-other-marketing-templates/create-an-email-template-with-html-code), the recommended way to opt links out of the link tracker is to change the class name to `inf-track-no`. The `nottracked` attribute is not documented publicly anywhere except in [this help page for a service called FeedBolt](https://www.feedbolt.com/how-do-i-stop-infusionsoft-from-breaking-my-links) (with which, despite the name, I have no affiliation whatsoever). Whether this means Infusionsoft has deprecated the `nottracked` attribute (as it's non-standard) is unclear.